# Get absolute paths to images instead of blank.gif

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm processing a few webs, so that I have a list with
absolute paths to images,with the following code:

```
for img in images:
    try:
      if img["src"].startswith("http"):
        abs_img_url = img["src"]
      else:
        abs_img_url = urljoin(url, img["src"])
    except KeyError:
      # src attribute does not exist
      continue
```

The problem is with this [webpage](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/speed-up-mozilla-firefox/), where I will get a lot of `blank.gif` images, though the browser will display other file which is stored in
`img["data-original"]` attribute. It's surprising that Firefox inspector
shows the correct image in `img["src"]` but when you view the source
you see it in `img["data-original"]`.

Could you explain this issue and how would you treat it programaticaly
to detect and download the right image, instead of `blank.gif`?

example image element giving bad result:

```
<img alt="browser cache backend" class="lazy aligncenter size-full wp-image-57323" data-original="http://11986-presscdn-0-77.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/browser-cache-backend.jpg" height="190" itemprop="image" sizes="(max-width: 540px) 100vw, 540px" src="http://11986-presscdn-0-77.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/online-tech-tips-2013/images/blank.gif" srcset="http://11986-presscdn-0-77.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/browser-cache-backend.jpg 540w, http://11986-presscdn-0-77.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/browser-cache-backend-300x106.jpg 300w, http://11986-presscdn-0-77.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/browser-cache-backend-80x28.jpg 80w" width="540"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that JavaScript is changing the source from the `data-original` attribute to the `src` attribute dynamically on load, and since BeautifulSoup does not process JS you end up with invalid `src` attributes to your images. With this in mind you have 2 options, either parse the `data-original` attribute or change your approach to something that process the JS code before you parse the page like Selenium or CasperJS or PhantomJS.

I think that searching for the correct attribute is a good way to go without overcomplicating your scraper.

```
my_images = []

for img in images:
    try:
        if img['src'].endswith('blank.gif'):
            my_images.append(img['data-original'])
        else:
            my_images.append(img['src'])
    except KeyError:
        continue

my_abs_images = [img if img.startswith('http') else urljoin(url, img) for img in my_images]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a conditional for detecting wether if the image is called blank.gif:

```
for img in images:
    try:
        if img["src"].startswith("http"):

        abs_img_url = img["src"]

        if img["src"][-9:]=='blank.gif':
            abs_img_url = img["data-original"]
      else:
        abs_img_url = urljoin(url, img["src"])
    except KeyError:
        # src attribute does not exist
        continue
```